# How does python know to add a space between a string literal and a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am currently learning python the hard way. In one of the exercises we print string literals with variables between them. I noticed that unlike other languages python automatically adds a space between a string literal and variables. I was just curious as to how it does that. Below is an example of what I mean.

example.py:

```
total_SO_questions_asked = 1
print "I have asked", total_SO_questions_asked, "question to SO thus far."
```

terminal:

```
$ python example.py
I have asked 1 question to SO thus far.
```

This is silly and not very important but I am curious, and I am hoping that SO can enlighten me!

Comment: Nothing clever is going on here internally.  `print` always separates its arguments with a space, no matter what they are.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=print#grammar-token-print_stmt

Comment: @iCodez - you shouldn't answer questions in comments, it leaves them in limbo...

Comment: I wanted to answer this but your comment is literally almost word for word what my answer would be and so I would be accused of stealing your comment and making it my answer...hence no can answer this question now.

Comment: This is exactly the documented behaviour of the print statement.  Voting to close as unclear what you're asking

Comment: @DrCord - My comment is only two sentences, with no documentation link nor explanation.  It was in no way meant as a proper answer to this question.  Because this behavior is clearly explained in the documentation, I was assuming that this question would be quickly downvoted/closed.  Yet, I didn't want the OP to go away empty handed, so I left that to help him.

Comment: this was as much about learning how to properly post a question on to SO as it was about my curiosity, if the existence of this question generates no value please close it. Thank you to those that commented and/or answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a cool feature of Python.

There are two things having multiple arguments does: It adds a space around the parameters as necassary, and it converts each of the arguments to a string seperately.

Let's look at how simple we can make potentially complicated code using these features:

```
a = 5
b = 3
c = a + b
print a, "plus", b, "equals", a+b
```

If we couldn't have a list of individually casted parameters, it'd look ugly:

```
print str(a) + " plus " + str(b) + " equals " + str(a+b)
```

From the Zen of Python, lines 1 and 3:

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>
> Simple is better than complex.

Check out the [Python reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! That was a very clear answer, especially relating it back to the to the Zen of Python, answering not only how python does this but why as well. OP is happy!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily print without spaces:

```
>>> aa = 'abcd'
>>> bb = 'efgh'
>>> n = 1
>>> print "%s%d%s" % (aa, n, bb)
abcd1efgh
>>>
```

Comment: It's better to use [```str.format()```](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for this (```print "{}{}{}".format(aa, n, bb)```). Regardless, you didn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing clever is going on here internally. `print` always separates its arguments with a space, no matter what they are.

(Answer ruthlessly stolen from iCodez's comment)